# How can I partition and format my disk to an accuracy of "LBA" by commands?

Tags: command-line, filesystems, partition

How can I partition `/dev/sdb` into `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`, and then format `/dev/sdb1` to exFAT ( or FAT32 ) from [LBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing)=1 to 2097152 by commands? ( LBA=0 is reserved for MBR )

Comment: You want to create a 1 MiB partition (2048 times 512 byte)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a loop device for testing:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp.img bs=1M count=100
modprobe loop
dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp.img bs=1M count=100
losetup /dev/loop0 tmp.img
```

And then:

```
 # parted --script /dev/loop0 unit s mklabel msdos \
   mkpart primary fat32 1 2048 mkpart primary fat32 2049 4096 print
 Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
 Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
 Model: Loopback device (loopback)
 Disk /dev/loop0: 204800s
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: msdos

 Number  Start  End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
  1      1s     2048s  2048s  primary               lba, type=0c
  2      2049s  4096s  2048s  primary               lba, type=0c
```

**formatting**

```
mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault. I edited my question. It should be LBA=2097152. (1GiB)